# Regex for string between a digit and character?

Tags: regex

I have a few different strings that look like this:

```
aaaa01b.site.com
bbbb01ccc.site.com
cccc02dd.site.com
dd03eeee.site.com
```

All I am interested in is the characters between the last numeric digit and the first full stop, ie

```
b
ccc
dd
eeee
```

Is there a regular expression that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
.*\d+([^.]+)\.
```

The characters you want should be available in the first capture group.

### Demo